# Partition corruption after resizing with KDE partition manager... lost the superblock?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, kde, data-recovery

I have an old 120 GB hard drive that I would like to use for backup. It had an old Lubuntu installation on it, while I'm currently running Kubuntu LTS. It had boot, root, home (ext4), and swap partitions on it. I decided to knock out all but the home partition, then extend that. KDE PM gladly resized it, and I should have written down exactly what it told me it was doing, but I remember that it shifted the beginning of the partition "to the right", and by 8... something? MiB?

In any case, that part of the operation took over an hour, and at the end of it, it turns out the partition isn't readable. e2fsck, etc. tell me that the superblock is corrupt, bad magic number, can't find backup superblocks. The alternative superblock suggestions do not work. I suspect the shift left the superblock behind and threw off the normal numbering scheme for backup superblocks. Is that even plausible? How would I recover from that?... presumably starting with rolling the beginning of the partition back to reincorporate the old superblock.

Possibly relevant info: this is an ancient IDE hard drive that I'm accessing through an IDE to SATA adapter. fdisk, etc. tell me it has a DOS partition table.

I *probably* backed up all the data on that drive long ago and have it stored on my external hard drive and from there to my current main hard drive, but I'd like to have the opportunity to check...